# ansible *when* say : "error while evaluating conditional"

Tags: ansible

I try to do something like that:

I have this playbook

```
---
- hosts: all 
  vars:
    user: myuser
    venv_name: venv
    only_deploy_code: "yes"
  roles:
    - my_venv
```

In roles/my_venv/tasks/main.yml::

```
---
- name: pip Install packages into virtualenv
  pip: name={{ item }} virtualenv="{{ home }}/{{ venv_name }}" virtualenv_site_packages="yes"
  with_items:
    - PyYAML
    - numexpr
  sudo_user: "{{ user }}"
  sudo: true
  when: only_code_deploy == "no"
```

but I get this error::

```
TASK: [akd_venv | pip Install packages into virtualenv]   
*********************** 
fatal: [vagrant] => error while evaluating conditional: only_code_deploy == "no"
```

Comment: Look at your variable names... you have `only_deploy_code` in your vars block and `only_code_deploy` in your task. Also you should use booleans instead of strings representing booleans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to omit the quotes around the `yes` and change your `when` statement like this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
   only_deploy_code: yes
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "This is yes message"
      when: not only_deploy_code
```

Tested on the local machine like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i "localhost," test.yml -c local
```

with the output:

```
PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I think this is the expected behaviour that you want, just modified the `when` statement if you want to skip it for `no` instead of `yes` like this:

```
when: only_deploy_code
```

Comment: Quotes don't matter. It is the misnamed variable.